# Street index to CSV/Excel file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel, data-driven-pages

Anyone know how to generate a street index for a map with accompnaying page numbers that are data driven? I am use the toolbox for creating the street index but exports to PDF however I need it to be in a csv file or excel. I have converted the PDF created file into excel but it is too messy and difficult to clean.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148626/creating-a-table-of-multiple-rows-and-columns-from-attribute-table?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148626/creating-a-table-of-multiple-rows-and-columns-from-attribute-table?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

For other's clarification, [the tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/localgovernment/10.2/index.html#/Create_Street_Index_Report/028s000000st000000/) you are referring to is custom written for a toolbox included with the [Fire Run Book](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/localgovernment/10.2/index.html#/What_is_Fire_Run_Book/028s000000nv000000/). I do not know the specifics of the tool, but it is written only to output a PDF. It *might* be possible for someone to modify it, but that would be beyond me.

However, a quick search returned the following method, taken from this [ESRI Knowledgebase article](http://support.esri.com/de/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39710).

> 1. Intersect the streets feature class with the map grid index feature class using the Spatial join tool.
> 2. Use the streets layer as the Target Features and the map grid index layer as the Join Features. Set the Join Operation to One-to-Many.
>      Leave the rest of the options as default. A new feature class is
>      created.
> 3. Open the new feature class' attribute table and add a new text field.
> 4. Concatenate the Street Name and the PageNumber fields (Field Calculate using [NAME]& "-"& [PageNumber]).
> 5. Summarize based on the new field. (In the open attribute table, right click the concatenated field and select Summarize.) Doing this
>      removes the duplicate entries. Select any other summarizations that
>      might be helpful.
> 6. Open the created dbf file in Excel and make changes as needed. Print or convert this table to the desired format and add it to the
>      Map Book.

There is also a script tool at the KB link above that could be used/modified. There is a slightly different method outlined in an Esri blog post from 2007 called [Creating street name indexes](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/11/08/creating-street-name-indexes/). Additionally, if you have access to the Production Mapping extension there is a tool called [Create Index Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01090000000t000000) that can do it.